# How to export Hair in Blender 4.0 with the new hair asset library, not the old particle system?

Tags: modifiers, export, import, hair, library

How would one go about exporting from Blender into iClone or Unreal with Blender's new hair asset system - not the particle system? Which file type would be best (FBX, Albemic, etc.)? Recommendations for settings? What if the hair curves have modifiers? Is it possible to "bake" the new hair system or something similar? Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.